How to prevent leakage current in a GPIO expander
I’m building a Bluetooth mod for the PlayStation portable. You can view its current progress here if interested.
It’s working great except for an issue in struggling to find a solution to.
I prefix all this with I’m a software guy learning electronics as I go (part of the reason for this project)
So it’s powered by an ESP32 and using a pair of MCP23008 GPIO Expander's to interface with the PSP. To trigger a button press for the PSP I mark a pin as an Input and send it low.
Now to save on battery life (the PSP’s battery is terrible) my mod board is only powered when the PSP is connected to its 5v charger.
However the mod board and psp share a common ground connection at all times.
Here lies my issue. When disconnected from power the psp thinks all it’s buttons are pressed at once.
I think the issue is because the GPIO expander allows a small leakage current when it is not powered on. Just enough for the PSP to think that button is pressed.
I’ve tried using a 2N2222 between the GPIO expanders VSS and ground, in my mind, to switch it off. Only providing current to the 2N2222’s base to turn it on when the Bluetooth mod board is powered on. Unfortunately this has the same issue.
When I removed the 2N2222 from the circuit but left the GPIO expander's VSS disconnected I was surprised to find the expander still functioned. Now the expander is I2c based with three address pins which are either connected to ground or +3v to select its address. I can only assume with VSs disconnected the expander is functioning because of the address pins connected to ground.
If this is true then i assume the current leaking could also be leaving through these grounded address pins and not just VSS. So any solution i try to the VSS pin would also have to be done to the address pins.
So my question is generally how can I solve this current leakage issue? Have the PSP and my mod board share a common ground but the PSP not think it’s buttons are pressed when the mod board is not powered on.
Could i use a mosfet of some sort to act as a switch to the mod board in it's entirety? Isolating the whole thing from the PSP unless connected to the PSP's charger? Admittedly i dont know enough to know if mosfet's can be used for such a situation, or if even they will have current leakage which will leave me in the same situation.
Hope this question makes sense and the project interesting enough to make it worth reading through my ramblings!
EDIT: As requested i have included schematics for the things i talking about.
So i have exported the schematic as a whole for context. Please be aware that this is my first electronics project. Ive learnt allot but i dont really know what im doing and may have followed many bad practices in build this schematic. Because i can't upload the PDF here i have just created an issue on the github and attached it there. You can access it here.
https://github.com/ste2425/PSP-Bluetooth/issues/11
So the specific area of the schematic relating to this issue is here:

We can see the VSS pin of each expander was connected to ground. This is where I discovered the issue.
So to fix it i tried this:

I used a 2N2222 as a switch to try and disconnect the expanders from the circuit when no 3.3v is applied. In my mind preventing the current leakage and solving the issue.
Except it did not. However when i removed the 2N2222 so the VSS pins are essentially disconnects like this:

To my suprise the expanders still work and can controll the PSP.
The A[n] pins are connected to ground to configure the I2C bus address so i assume they are whats allowing the expander to function with the VSS pin disconnected. But truthfully i have no idea.
Thanks for any help.

Can you post  a schematic diagram?

@Aaron Sure thing.  I’m not at the computer but I will fire up KiCad and include the schematic tomorrow

@Aaron added schematics and more context

Probably the unpowered ICs are being powered instead via the input ESD protection diodes, a situation that would look like this:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
As you can see, a high output from IC1 finds a path for current into IC2 via D1, raising the the right-hand supply potential. A similar situation arises if you switch the ground supply for IC2, except then the culprit is D2, and IC1 would sink current instead. One way to solve the problem is with a diode and resistor:

simulate this circuit
Diode D3 prevents the left IC from sourcing current. A low output from IC1 is able to pull the input low, via D3, and R2 holds the input high otherwise. D3 is likely to leak a few microamps, though, and the supply rail can still rise very slightly (as indicated on the voltmeter), depending on what else is connected between the supply rail and ground.
I use schottky diode for D3, so that a "low" at the input will be about +0.3V, but you could probably employ a regular silicon diode like a 1N4148, to reduce leakage down to nanoamps. That would cause the low signal to be +0.6V or so; check your IC datasheet to verify if that's still low enough to be interpreted as logic low.
If you don't mind a signal inversion, the leakage problem can be solved with a MOSFET:

simulate this circuit
The MOSFET's gate completely isolates the two ICs, except for their common ground, and there's no loop for current to flow around.
